# Morris Line chart Y axis scale not displayed fully? why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Morris Line chart is not showing full y axis scale value. It means the left hand side (scale) is displayed only two digit number and help me how to resolve?

[image: Screenshot of chart]

asp.net

1. morris & raphael-min.js is added in header script section
2. In form tag div is declared.
3. javascript :

```js
var datajson=[{period:2013,MaleFemale:22182237,Male:20190125,Female:1992112},{period:2014,MaleFemale:21884833,Male:19874210,Female:2010623},{period:2015,MaleFemale:21569162,Male:19543674,Female:2025488},{period:2016,MaleFemale:21259490,Male:19218016,Female:2041474},{period:2017,MaleFemale:20959502,Male:18901107,Female:2058395},{period:2018,MaleFemale:20657767,Male:18581646,Female:2076121},{period:2019,MaleFemale:20360597,Male:18265939,Female:2094658},{period:2020,MaleFemale:20071747,Male:17958012,Female:2113735},{period:2021,MaleFemale:19778233,Male:17646048,Female:2132185},{period:2022,MaleFemale:19489609,Male:17338791,Female:2150818},{period:2023,MaleFemale:19203678,Male:17034845,Female:2168833}];

$('#trendchart1').empty();
new Morris.Line({
  element: 'trendchart1',
  data: datajson,
  xkey: ['period'],
  ykeys: ['Male', 'Female'],
  labels: ['Total Male', 'Total Female'],
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  resize: true,
  pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['gray', 'red']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="trendchart1" style="height: 250px; width:600px"></div>
```

JSON:

```
period  MaleFemale  Male        Female
2013    22182237    20190125    1992112
2014    21884833    19874210    2010623
2015    21569162    19543674    2025488
2016    21259490    19218016    2041474
2017    20959502    18901107    2058395
2018    20657767    18581646    2076121
2019    20360597    18265939    2094658
2020    20071747    17958012    2113735
2021    19778233    17646048    2132185
2022    19489609    17338791    2150818
2023    19203678    17034845    2168833
```

Comment: I fixed your snippet to work ;-p

Comment: The y-step if set to `7,500,000`. What is the issue?

Comment: if i give step:750000, left side label 00 is showing (not a full value : 7,500,000. last two digit only showing. why?

Comment: hi polywhril, i can't able to attach .png file, can you send me ur mail id?

Comment: thanks i have added the image:http://i.imgur.com/din6qB4.png. left hand side scale 25 94 63 (two digits) only showing.

Comment: i think css issue. http://imgur.com/yzAm3ex,VKfsbIp

Comment: You can remove your last 3 comments above as they have been added to your question. Are you sure the JSON data is correct? Your result should look like the snippet in your question.